# Patterns for displaying payment of product with points / frequent flyer

Tags: e-commerce, payment

Pattern for displaying payment of product with point system such as frequent flyer points.

So the customer is buying a product for $300 and on the payment screen has the option to pay for this with points. However, he only has enough points to pay $100 off the price. This is basic display of managing how many points to use...

> (POINTS) ===========|--------------------------- (DOLLARS)
>
> 478pts = $100  ................................................ $200

As for the actual payment breakdown

> PAYMENT SUMMARY
>
> Product X............................. $300
>
> Points (478pts)..................... $100
>
> Payable................................ $200

The display of whats going to be charged to their credit card, don't think its quite clear yet... any suggestions or examples of where this is done. I have never used a point paying system so I am struggling to find examples.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the case, you want the customer to **think of the price in terms of points**, not in terms of currency.  If they think in terms of points, they will be more likely to spend them, and I take it that is your goal.

So ignoring the poor layout here, I would rather have something like:

> Price....................980 points
>   ...........................-478 points (from your balance / wallet)
>   To pay.................502 points ($ 289)